# How to check build sanity using Maven for TestNG and Java?

Tags: java, maven, testng

I want to catch the compilation/code errors in my build using a maven command (in a Jenkins job).

I tried:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

This works fine but fails to catch few Java errors.
For example, wrong package path in a Java class:

SampleTest.java

```
package apps/incorrect/path; //incorrect package path

import ....
```

This isn't getting caught with ***mvn clean install -DskipTests*** as it results in a successful build.

However, during the eventual run using ***mvn clean test***, it fails as expected with the below error:

```
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] apps/correct/path (wrong name: oracle/incorrect/path)
```

Is there a different maven command to check the build sanity and also alert me to these Java code errors?

Comment: Something is very wrong here. The `install` phase should have run the `test` phase which ought to have compiled the test classes, even if you specify `-Dskiptests` (which should be spelled with capital 'T'). http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skipTests Moreover, this property only suppresses the *execution* of the tests, not the compilation of them. Please post the relevant parts of your POM.

Answer (score 1):

Try below command

```
>mvn test -Dtestng.mode.dryrun=true
```